# Sort the listview

Tags: java, android, file, listview

I am arranging the listview of my mp3 files in alphabetical order but it is making an error that if the file is outside it will be correct and if it is in a subdirectory of that directory then it will take the word The first thing that sorts the files into that directory

For example, if I have 5 files **a, b, c, d, e**,  in *sdcard1 / music /* there are 3 files **c, d, e** and **a ,b** in *sdcard1 / music / xmusic /* then it will be  **c, d, e, a, b**

This is code

```
ArrayList<File> Songs = findSongs("/storage/sdcard1/Music");

Collections.sort(Songs, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
public int compare(File name2, File name1) {
          return name2.compareTo(name1);
            }
        });
```

And

```
public ArrayList<File> findSongs(String rootPath) {
        ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();           
            File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
            File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
             fileList.addAll(findSongs(file.getAbsolutePath()));
              } else {                  
             if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3") && file.isFile() && file.length() > 100) {
          fileList.add(file);
                }                
             }
          }                
          return fileList;
      }
```

Thank !

Comment: What is the output you would like to see ABCDE, or CDEAB, difficult to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Comparator` sorts the files based on their absolute path. To use only the name of the file, use a `Comparator` like this:

```
ArrayList<File> Songs = findSongs("/storage/sdcard1/Music");
Collections.sort(Songs, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        return file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName());
    }
});
```

Your `Comparator` would compare `sdcard1/music/c` with `sdcard1/music/xmusic/a` and will say that the first value is first alphabetically. Using the one provided above, it will compare `c` and `a` which will provide the correct order between the files.